# Output not redirecting to file

Tags: grep, ping, redirect

I'm experiencing weirdness (or rather showing Linux ignorance).

I want to learn the probability distribution of ping requests, so I thought I'd ping some random site for a while, grep the output to save the ms only, and then redirect to a file. I do this.

```
ping www.doggiedooley.com | grep -o "[[:digit:]]*.[[:digit:]]* ms" > ping.txt
```

I had high hopes for this command, but even though the file is created, it contains nothing, even after a while. If I remove the redirection, output is shown. I can even redirect the output successfully to another terminal.

```
ping www.doggiedooley.com | grep -o "[[:digit:]]*.[[:digit:]]* ms" > /dev/pts/1
```

Why is the first command not working properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a stdout buffering issue. You can turn it off before redirecting with:

```
stdbuf -o0
```

So use:

```
 ping www.doggiedooley.com | stdbuf -o0 grep -o "[[:digit:]]*.[[:digit:]]* ms" > ping.txt
```

Or use `-c` option of `ping` to limit sending packets.