# How to save terminal output to a file every 1 s?

Tags: command-line

I want to save a terminal output in a file **but every 1 second.**

I want to save tcpdump output in a file but the output will be saved after the command ends and I want to save it every time when the output changes.

I use the command

```
sudo tcpdump > output.txt
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - if you are asking about buffering then see [Output not redirecting to file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280443/output-not-redirecting-to-file)

Answer (score 1):

I found a good solution:

`stdbuf -oL sudo tcpdump &> output.txt`

:)